# sort two arrays accordingly in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have two global arrays: `X` and `Fx`.

I'm sorting the `X` array and trying to shift the accordingly value in the fx array as X shifted. All of that by bubble sort.

bay nothing happens in the fx array.

for the following example:

```
x-( 3 2 1) fX-(1 2 3)
```

the Out will be

```
x-(1 2 3 ) fx-(3 2 1)
```

Here is my code:

```
function extractLoopPoints
{
bubble_sort
echo " inputX: ${xArray[@]}"
echo " inputX: ${fxArray[@]}"
echo "output: $(bubble_sort ${xArray[@]})"
echo "output fx: $(bubble_sort ${fxArray[@]})"
} 


function bubble_sort()
{  

    local xArray=($@)  local fxArray=($@) max=$(($# - 1))
    while ((max > 0))
    do
        local i=0
        while ((i < max))
        do
            if [ ${xArray[$i]} \> ${xArray[$((i + 1))]} ]
            then
                local t=${xArray[$i]}
                local tf=${fxArray[$i]}
                xArray[$i]=${xArray[$((i + 1))]}
                fxArray[$i]=${fxArray[$((i + 1))]}
                xArray[$((i + 1))]=$t 
                fxArray[$((i + 1))]=$tf
            fi
            ((i += 1))
        done
        ((max -= 1))
    done
    echo ${xArray[@]}
    echo ${fxArray[@]}
}
```

Comment: `$@` is the same when assigned to xArray and fxArray.

Comment: thanks, but how I change it that it'll be to the second array

Comment: How do you want to pass two arrays as parameters?

Comment: the tow array are defined as a global array in the code. so I can  the in the accesses to them from the function.(that what I assume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array are global

here is the right way

```
function bubble_sort()
{   
    local max=${#xArray[@]}
    size=${#xArray[@]}
    while ((max > 0))
    do
        local i=0
        while ((i < max))
        do
            if [ "$i" != "$(($size-1))" ] #array will not be out of bound
            then
                if [ ${xArray[$i]} \> ${xArray[$((i + 1))]} ]
                   then
                   local t=${xArray[$i]}
                   xArray[$i]=${xArray[$((i + 1))]}
                   xArray[$((i + 1))]=$t
                    
                   local tf=${fxArray[$i]}
                   fxArray[$i]=${fxArray[$((i + 1))]}
                  fxArray[$((i + 1))]=$tf
                 fi
             fi
            ((i += 1))
        done
        ((max -= 1))
    done
}
```